# Qual a diferença entre function() {} e () => {}? Por que não funciona o $http.get?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sintaxe

Quando eu uso

```
 $http.get('/products').then((response) => {
   this.products = response.data;
   this.allProducts = response.data;
 });
```

a página é carregada com os produtos no Google Chrome, mas quando eu uso

```
$http.get('/products').then(function(response) {
  this.products = response.data;
  this.allProducts = response.data;
});
```

Os produtos não são carregados :(

Por causa do Safari e Safari Mobile, eu não estou conseguindo usar a sintaxe () => do ES2015. O navegador dá um erro de "compilação".

Alguém sabe o que eu preciso fazer para utilizar o `function(response) {}` e obter os produtos?

Obrigado

Comment: Aparece algum erro no console, a requisição é feita?

Comment: a requisição é feita sim. Quando eu dou um `console.log(response.data)` ele me devolve o array de produtos certinho. Mas aparece um erro : `TypeError: Cannot set property 'products' of undefined`

Comment: Tenta inicializar a lista de produtos, `products = [];` no escopo global

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Como notei que não explicaram a diferença entre `() => {}` e `function() {}`, então apesar de haver uma resposta marcada como correta, vou explicar esta diferença.

Primeiramente é muito comum achar que ambos os códigos são equivalentes, já que o `ES6` trouxe diversos `syntax sugar` para deixar o código mais legível e conciso, as `arrow functions` são normalmente confundidas com as `functions` do `ES5`. Mas indo direto ao ponto existem cinco diferenças entre ambos os códigos:

### Contexto

`Arrow functions` possuem `this léxico` enquanto o modelo normal possui `this dinâmico`. Isso significa que `arrow functions` herdam o contexto local de onde foi declarado, enquanto o modelo normal possui o contexto associado ao objeto que ele está vinculado no momento da chamada (se ele não estiver associado a ninguém na chamada, ele assumirá `this` automaticamente como o contexto global, que no caso dos navegadores é `window`)

```
var normal = function() {
  return this === obj;
};

var arrow = () => {
  return this === window;
};

var obj = { normal: normal, arrow: arrow };

obj.normal(); // true
obj.arrow(); // true

normal(); // false
```

### Constructor

`Arrow functions` não podem ser `constructors`, então não é possível usar o operador `new` com a mesma.

```
var Normal = function() {};
var Arrow = () => {};

new Normal(); // Normal {}
new Arrow(); // Arrow is not a constructor
```

### Arguments

`Arrow functions` não possui o objeto array-like `arguments`.

```
var noop = () => {
  return arguments;
}

noop(); // ReferenceError: arguments is not defined
```

### Nome de função

Expressões de função podem ser nomeadas explicatamente, isso é útil em alguns cenários que envolvem recursão e para em casos de exceção fica mais fácil de rastrear o código, visto que o nome da função é usado na pilha de exceção mostrada ao desenvolvedor. Só que `Arrows Functions` não podem ser nomeadas explicitamente, elas acabam herdando o nome da variável onde foi criada.

```
var fn = function nome() {};
fn.name; // nome

var fn = () => {};
fn.name; // fn
```

### Retorno

Expressões de função precisam declarar explicitamente qual será o retorno da função, enquanto `Arrow Functions` permitem escrever em um modelo encurtado onde a última expressão analisada será o retorno da função quando é omitido as chaves `{}`.

```
var fn = function() { return 1; }; // retorna 1

var fn = () => 1; // retorna 1
var fn = () => (1, 2, 3); // retorna 3, última expressão avaliada

var fn = () => { 1 }; // retorna undefined
var fn = () => { return 1 }; // retorna 1
```

### O que seria um modelo equivalente de `() => {}` então?

Ignorando o caso de que `arrow functions` não podem ser usadas como `constructors` e não recebem `arguments`, o modelo mais equivalente entre `arrow functions` e funções tradicionais seria este:

```
// modelo nomeado
var name = (() => { /* code */ })
var name = (function name() { /* code */ }).bind(this)

// modelo anônimo
(() => { /* code */ })
(function() { /* code */ }).bind(this)
```

Neste caso o `code` pode ser exatamente o mesmo entre os dois modelos e eles irão funcionar exatamente igual. Mas claro, existem outras maneiras de simular o comportamento das `arrow functions`. Um deles é armazenar o contexto `this` em uma variável e usar essa variável na função tradicional em vez do seu próprio `this`, o que as outras respostas mostraram.

Comment: Bem colocado! Foquei no texto da questão e esqueci do título.

Comment: Boa resposta! Acho interessante mencionar a syntax sugar do return com arrow function. Exemplo function (test) { return test } pode ser escrito apenas com test => test. O que acha de adicionar um exemplo a resposta?

Comment: Bom ponto levantado, @DorivalZanetto. Também preciso atualizar a parte de `Nome de função`, visto que `Arrow functions` agora recebem por padrão o nome da variável onde foi declarado na propriedade name.

Comment: Bacana @GabrielKatakura. Fiz uma pergunta voltada a perda de referências em funções que apenas consegui resolver com arrow functions. O que acha de tentar elaborar uma resposta? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/178215/perda-de-refer%C3%AAncia-em-chamada-de-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o

Comment: @DorivalZanetto acabei de ver sua pergunta, mas ela acabou de receber uma resposta (que eu olhei e ela está correta). Eu consigo pensar em outras quatro soluções plausíveis para resolver o seu problema lá, mais de noite eu posto uma resposta

Comment: Obrigado, tinha alterado uma rotina para uso de arrow functions e meu código parou. Acho que deixei passar despercebido que o contexto muda. Sua explicação foi de grande ajuda para firmar o conhecimento!

Answer (score 7):

Posso estar enganado, mas li um artigo de AngularJs (não estou achando a referência agora) que tratava essa questão em específica quando combinada com o uso do método `syntax as`, onde é comum usar `this` dentro do `controller`.

O grande problema quanto a isso é saber a qual escopo o `this` está atribuído, pois para que seja possível passar os dados para a view, é necessário que o mesmo esteja no escopo do `controller`.

É aí que acredito que esteja o seu erro, pois o `this` está no escopo do `$http`

```
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    this.products = []; //Aqui ele está no escopo do controller - Irá passar para view

    $http.get('minha/url/aqui').then(function(response){
        this.products = response.data; //Aqui ele está no escopo do $http - Não irá passar para view
    })
})
```

O que normalmente é feito, para garantir que você sempre use o escopo do `controller` quando atribuído ao `this`, é criar uma variável no início do `controller` e usá-la, ao invés de usar `this`. Assim:

```
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    var vm = this; //Pode ser vm (ViewModel) ou outra variável de sua preferência

    vm.products = []; //Aqui ele está no escopo do controller - Irá passar para view

    $http.get('minha/url/aqui').then(function(response){
        vm.products = response.data; //Está apenas atualizando o products definido anteriormente
    })
})
```

Comment: Ótima resposta. Uma outra alternativa se não for usar a lista na view é não usar o `this`.

Answer (score 0):

Faço assim e funciona:

```
angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp')
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.content = [];

    $http.get("/content")
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.content = response.data;
    });

});
```

Retirado e baseado de: [Angular HTTP W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_http.asp)

Comment: Eu precisava que a variável products fosse do controller e não $scope.

Comment: Só sei fazer assim como a documentação do W3Schools e do próprio Angular fazem. :-(