# Array busca por nome

Tags: javascript

Tem como usar  Arrow Function neste exemplo? Se sim como ficaria? Qual a melhor forma de fazer busca pelo valor?

```js
var msg =  ["Orange", "Melancia", "Abobora"];
 
var fruta = "Melancia"
  
buscar(fruta);

 function buscar(str){
  if(msg.indexOf(str) > -1){
    console.log(str);
  }else{
    console.log("Fruta não encontrada");
  }      
 }
```

Comment: Não deu para entender o que você quer. Você busca na lista pelo índice onde está a palavra "melancia" para no final retornar "melancia"? Não fez sentido para mim.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss vou arrumar a lógica pra fazer sentido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ela ficaria assim:

```js
var lista =  ["Orange", "Melancia", "Abobora"];
const buscar = str => (lista.indexOf(str) > -1) ? console.log('Encontrada') : console.log("Não encontrada");
buscar("Melancia");
buscar("Não existe");
```

Você também pode utilizar o método [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/contains), mas segundo a documentação ele ainda esta em testes e pode ocorrer alterações na sintaxe e no comportamento.

> Esta é uma tecnologia experimental, parte da proposta ECMAScript 2016 (ES7).
>   Como a especificação desta tecnologia não se estabilizou, verifique a tabela de compatibilidade para uso em vários navegadores. Observe também que a sintaxe e o comportamento de uma tecnologia experimental estão sujeitos a alterações na futura versão dos navegadores à medida que a especificação muda. - Tradução livre.

```js
var lista =  ["Orange", "Melancia", "Abobora"];
const buscar = str => (lista.includes(str)) ? console.log('Encontrada') : console.log("Não encontrada");
buscar("Melancia");
buscar("Não existe");
```

#### Referências

- [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/contains) - [Compatibilidade](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/contains#Compatibilidade)
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
- [Qual a diferença entre function() {} e () => {}? Por que não funciona o $http.get?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/143399)

Answer (score 0):

```
var msg = ["Orange", "Melancia", "Abobora"];


var buscar = nome => msg.filter((elemento) => elemento.toLowerCase() === nome.toLowerCase())
```

invocando função

```
buscar("Melancia")
```

Comment: `filter` retorna um novo `array` logo teria que fazer uma condição para saber se obteve retorno.