# Como este código quebra a string em partes?

Tags: javascript

Através dessa pergunta: [How to remove all element from array except the first one in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39510821/how-to-remove-all-element-from-array-except-the-first-one-in-javascript).

Adaptei o código para minha necessidade.

```js
var rua = 'RUA NILO PEÇANHA';
const head = ([x, ...xs]) => x
const tail = ([x, ...xs]) => xs
console.log(`${head(rua).toUpperCase()}${tail(rua).join('').toLowerCase()}`)
```

Acabei escolhendo o código que tem as duas contantes `head` e `tail`.

Eu nunca vi algo parecido com: `([x, ...xs]) => x`.
Sei que está sendo utilizado o `Spread` juntamente com funções de seta(`arrow functions`).

Dúvida:

- Como um código como `([x, ...xs]) => x` retornou apenas a primeira letra e `([x, ...xs]) => xs` retornou todo o restante?

Comment: Mas permita-me uma observação: o título da pergunta aborda uma questão e o conteúdo outras.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss isso é o Spread?

Comment: *Spread*, na verdade :D Sim, é uma das utilizações dele

Comment: Sobre arrow functions, ver [Qual a diferença entre function() {} e () => {}? Por que não funciona o $http.get?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/143399/74) e [O que significa o operador “=>”?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/114367/74)

Comment: Não vou por como resposta, pois não sei completamente o princípio, mas vou tentar ajudar com alguma informação:
Strings são cadeias de caracteres, ou seja, podem ser consideradas arrays de letras concatenadas. Essa é a parte que não sei exatamente como funciona.
`([x, ...xs]) => x` basicamente pega um array com indefinidos valores, e retorna apenas o primeiro valor, `x`. O mesmo vale para a outra, pega todos os valores que não são o primeiro, os `xs`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As funções `head` e `tail` fazem um uso "esperto" do operador de *spread* e do fato de strings permitirem acesso caractere a caractere com o uso de colchetes.

Quando se declara que o argumento delas é `[x, ...xs]`, estamos dizendo que a função recebe uma array. Quando passamos uma string, ela é tratada como uma array de caracteres.

Por exemplo, se chamarmos `head` passando `abcd`:

```
head("abcd")
```

O que a função recebe internamente é:

```
["a", ["b", "c", "d"]]
```

A primeira posição do array, `x`, é o primeiro caractere. Os demais serão armazenados na segunda posição da array, que por sua vez é outra array, `xs`. Repare que no seu código há um `.join('')` no resultado de `tail`. Isso porque `tail` retorna array, que precisa ser convertida para string pelo `join` para que o método `toUpperCase` possa ser chamado em seguida, já que ele só se aplica a strings.

Comment: Esclarecido as dúvidas, muito obrigado!