# Como dart interpreta uma ()=>{x,y,z} arrow em funções lambda/anônima

Tags: flutter, dart

Tem uma pergunta semelhante [aqui (referente a javascript)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/143399/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-function-e-por-que-n%C3%A3o-funciona-o-http-ge) porém acredito que existem características diferentes na implementação com `Dart`.

Exemplo em Dart:

```
void main() { 
  printName(() => { //ex:1
        print('nome1'),
        print('nome2'),
      });

  printName(() { //ex:2
    print('nome3');
    print('nome4');
  });
}

printName(Function printNames) {
  printNames();
}
```

No primeiro exemplo a expressão lambda com `arrow function` os comandos são 'delimitados' por virgula, o compilador interpreta os dois do mesmo modo ou tem alguma diferença?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso é porque em Dart, `big arrow function` sempre denota um retorno.

Diferente de JavaScript, em Dart, quando você abre chaves após a flecha (`=>`) do `big arrow function`, você não está abrindo um escopo, você está abrindo um `Map` ou um `Set`.

Ou seja, com a seguinte função:

```
printName(() => { //ex:1
    print('nome1'),
    print('nome2'),
});
```

Você está declarando um `Set` que terá os valores retornados pelas funções `print('nome1')` e `print('nome2')`, o que não deveria ser possível, pois a função `print` é `void`, sem retorno. Como em Dart, dentro de um `Set` os valores são separados por virgula, a sintaxe exige uma virgula, e não ponto e virgula entre os valores.

Então, já que na pergunta Dart foi comparado com JavaScript, aqui está a equivalência das funções:

Funções equivalentes (sem retorno):

```
// Dart
arr.forEach((x) {
    print(x);
});

// JavaScript
arr.forEach((x) => {
    console.log(x);
});
```

Funções equivalentes (retornam um Map/Object):

```
// Dart
arr.map((x) => { "val": x });

// JavaScript
arr.map((x) => ({ "val": x }));
```